# Show <ng-template> where it is located in angular template using a directive

Tags: angular, validation, input, angular-reactive-forms, directive

I am creating an Angular directive to be used on `<input type='text' formControlName="queryInput">` elements to display validation messages for the `formControl`.

The idea is:

1. If an `[errorTemplateRef]="errorTemplate"` is passed to the directive, it should use the provided template to display the error message, **positioning the template where it was declared**.
2. If no `errorTemplateRef` is provided, the directive should add a simple `<div>Validation error</div>` right after the input element.

I have no issues implementing point 2. However, I am facing problems with point 1.
I can't figure out how to 'render' the template while passing it a context (the error message) through the directive.

Could you please help me with this issue?

**Angular Template:**

```html
<form
    [formGroup]="formGroup"
    (ngSubmit)="onSubmitSearch()"
    class="flex w-full shadow-default"
>
    <input
        formControlName="queryInput"
        type="text"
        class="w-full h-full border-0 bg-white rounded-l-md"
        appInput
        [showError]="showError"
        [errorTemplateRef]="errorTemplate"
    />
    <button
        type="submit"
        class="flex justify-center items-center w-29 ml-1 p-3 bg-white rounded-r-md"
    >
        <span class="w-3/6 text-blue font-semibold text-sm tracking-wide uppercase">Cerca</span>

        <app-icon
            class="w-3/6 text-indaco"
            name="mdi:magnify"
            size="16"
        ></app-icon>
    </button>
</form>

<ng-template
    #errorTemplate
    let-message
    ><p class="text-crimson-red">Error: {{ message }}</p>
</ng-template>
```

**appInput Directive - in this moment it replace a ng-tamplate with a simple , but i want to use it**

```js
@Directive({
    selector: '[appInput]',
    standalone: true,
})
export class AppInputDirective implements OnInit, OnChanges, OnDestroy {
    @Input() showError = false;
    @Input() errorTemplateRef: TemplateRef<unknown> | undefined;

    private _errorElement: HTMLElement | undefined;
    private _errorPlaceholderElement: HTMLElement | undefined;
    private _errorSubscription: Subscription | undefined;

    constructor(
        private _el: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>,
        private _renderer: Renderer2,
        private _ngControl: NgControl,
    ) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        // If there's a placeholder to display the error, use it;
        // otherwise, create a div element below the input.
        this._errorPlaceholderElement = <HTMLElement>this.errorTemplateRef?.elementRef.nativeElement;

        const inputParent = <HTMLElement>this._renderer.parentNode(this._el.nativeElement);

        // Create a div element for the error message.
        this._errorElement = <HTMLElement>this._renderer.createElement('div');
        this._renderer.addClass(this._errorElement, 'text-coral-red');

        const wrapperElement = <HTMLElement>this._renderer.createElement('div');

        if (!this._errorPlaceholderElement && inputParent) {
            const wrapperClasses = ['flex', 'flex-col', 'gap-1'];
            inputParent.classList.contains('w-full') && wrapperClasses.push('w-full');
            inputParent.classList.contains('h-full') && wrapperClasses.push('h-full');
            wrapperElement.classList.add(...wrapperClasses);

            this._renderer.insertBefore(inputParent, wrapperElement, this._el.nativeElement);
            this._renderer.appendChild(wrapperElement, this._el.nativeElement);

            // Insert the error element after the target element.
            this._renderer.insertBefore(inputParent, this._errorElement, this._el.nativeElement.nextSibling);
        }

        // If there's a placeholder, position the error in its place.
        if (this._errorPlaceholderElement) {
            // Replace the original element with the new one.
            const parent = <HTMLElement>this._renderer.parentNode(this._errorPlaceholderElement);
            this._renderer.insertBefore(parent, this._errorElement, this._errorPlaceholderElement);
            this._renderer.removeChild(parent, this._errorPlaceholderElement);
        }
    }

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
        if (changes['showError']?.currentValue) {
            this._errorSubscription = this._ngControl.statusChanges
                ?.pipe(startWith(1))
                .subscribe(() => this._updateErrorDisplay());
        } else {
            this._errorSubscription?.unsubscribe();
        }
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this._errorSubscription?.unsubscribe();
    }

    private _updateErrorDisplay(): void {
        this._renderer.setProperty(this._errorElement, 'innerText', null);
        if (this._ngControl.errors) {
            const firstErrorKey = Object.keys(this._ngControl.errors)[0];
            const errorValue = <{ [key: string]: unknown }>this._ngControl.errors[firstErrorKey];

            const errorMessage = fillInPlaceholders(validationErrorString[firstErrorKey], errorValue);
            if (errorMessage) {
                this._renderer.setProperty(this._errorElement, 'innerText', errorMessage);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this moment it replace a ng-tamplate with a simple, but i want to use it